# Trying to use variable in MySQL INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am a php and MySQL newbie. What I have done is created an html form with a `<select>` dropdown. Based on the selection from the form, it changes the `$_SESSION[campaignID]` variable. Changing the selection in the form is supposed to then change what displays on the page. The page consists of a forum style post that allows users to fill out a textarea and then submit it into the MySQL database into a table called "posts." On this same page I then display the contents of the "posts" table.

What I have done is in the posts MySQL table, I have added a campaignID row. Then in my campaigns table I also have a campaignID row. The campaignID in campaigns table auto increments every time a campaign is created. Then with the earlier mentioned dropdown I can select the campaign I want, and it should then show all posts with the same campaignID as the campaign I selected.

I can verify that the `$_SESSION[campaignID]` is changing when i select the various options. Because when I do that and then save another post, it takes the session variable campaignID and saves it properly in the posts table.

Now what I need it to do, is when I change the drop down (which then changes `$_SESSION[campaignID]`) I need it to display the posts that share the same campaignID as the selected campaign. I am just not able to get it to display when trying to put a variable in my INNER JOIN query. I have a feeling the info I have provided may not be enough, but not sure what else I need to include here. Help?

#### Code that contains the INNER JOIN query and displays the various rows of posts table

### UPDATED

```
    <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","dorians","ds2953!b67P$","aldentec");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$campaignID = $_SESSION['campaignID'];


$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT posts.postDate, posts.postName, posts.postEntry FROM posts INNER JOIN campaigns ON posts.campaignID=" . $campaignID);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<div id='campaignPostContainer'>";
  echo "<ul class='campaignPostBox'>";
  echo "<p class='postInfo'>";
  echo "Posted on:";
  echo "<li>" . $row['postDate'] . "</li>";
  echo "</p>";
  echo "<p class='postInfo'>";
  echo "Posted by:";
  echo "<li>" . $row['postName'] . "</li>";
  echo "</p>";
  echo "<li class='postEntry'>" . $row['postEntry'] . "</li>";
  echo "</ul>";
  echo "</div>";
  echo "<hr>";
  }


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Remove double quotes at the end. Make it `ON posts.campaignID=" . $campaignID);`

Comment: Did that, still no luck.

Comment: If u echo $campaignID what it returns after the line $campaignID = '$_SESSION[campaignID]';

Comment: `$campaignID = '$_SESSION[campaignID]';` remove single quotes

Comment: This is weird, it echoes back `$_SESSION[campaignID]`

Comment: Ok removed the single quotes and it is half way working. However it is echoing each row 3 times

Comment: The multiple record could be of various reason what is the complete query you get ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Sorry I am still a newbie.

Comment: Depending on how `$_SESSION['campaignID]` is set, the sample code may be vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html), which is a very serious [security risk](http://bobby-tables.com/). To fix this hole (and other reasons), use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements), passing values as parameters to the statement rather than interpolating them directly into the string. You should also look into [PDO](http://www.php.net/PDO), which has a nicer interface. The site you save may just be your own.

Comment: SO is a Q&A site, not a forum. Edits shouldn't change the essential nature of the problem. If there are multiple issues with the code, each should get a separate question.

Comment: back to the first question I asked what is the value of $campaignID ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going into a use-prepared-statements rant...

You're not pulling the session variable, but assigning `$campaignId` to literally the string `$_SESSION[campaignID]`.

Change your line:

```
 $campaignID = '$_SESSION[campaignID]';
```

to:

```
 $campaignID = $_SESSION['campaignID'];
```

Also, your query is going to generate a cross product unless you define something in your ON clause like:

```
SELECT posts.postDate, posts.postName, posts.postEntry FROM posts 
   INNER JOIN campaigns ON posts.campaignID= $campaignID
         AND posts.campaignID= campaigns.id
```

Comment: Yes that did help show the correct posts now. What is weird though is it is echoing each entry back 3 times per post.

Comment: @Aldentec Do you have multiple post or revisions of a post in that table?  Run the query manually for one CampaignID and see if you get several records

Comment: Nope no multiple posts within the table.

Comment: Your inner join on clause in missing anything limiting the cross product of campaign and post table

Comment: That makes sense, what could I add to limit it per entry?

Comment: @Aldentec no,  you need to link the campaing table to the post table... see my update

Comment: Ah this did it! I had to change campaigns.id to campaigns.campaignID in the end, but otherwise the code you provided did the trick. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The value should be in single quote `'` so you may try this

```
posts.campaignID='" . $campaignID ."'"
```

instead of

```
posts.campaignID=" . $campaignID
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow and thank you for your effort! Unfortunately, your answer is not very helpful. Please *explain* your answer and avoid code-only answers. To learn more, see our tips on [writing great answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).